# Fix quotes in server-rendered html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to fix error, when I get from server html (in plain text) which I need to append to page with javascript and jquery.
Html from server contains an error in html format:

```
<input id="email_id" name="email_id" type="text" value="<a href="mailto:my@email.com">my@email.com</a>" />
```

In this string `"mailto:my@email.com"` showld be in single quotes, but server response contains double quotes. And jquery recognize that value of this input is only `"<a href="`.
How can I replace these double quotes with single quotes using javascript and jquery?

Comment: How this text box is generated? server side?

Comment: Yes, on the server side. And on the server side I can change only those parts of code, where this html is already in plain text.

Comment: @user1858864 what language

Comment: @user1858864 is this code being injected(ajax) or posted as a whole to the client's broweser ?

Comment: can u please show us some code?

Comment: @ Royi Namir it's injected with ajax and jquery so I can change this part of code.

Comment: @user3571366 its very simple: 
var el = $(data); //html from ajax
input.append(el);

Answer (score 0):

You can't. By the time JavaScript has access to the data, it will have already been parsed into the DOM and you'll have an unintelligible mess of invalid attributes.

You need to fix the problem at the source (before it gets to the browser)